# max-text-length solution for SVG text?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to make some text fit into a specific width on my SVG, I noticed that the `text-length` attribute gets me almost there, but it has the problem of stretching the text in case it's too short.

[image]
[image]

Either `spacingAdnGlyphs` and `spacing` are not involved in the behavior I'm looking for, they define how to stretch the text. What I want is to prevent the stretching from happening at all if it's not required in order to make it fit its container. So a short text should not be altered.

```
<text
  length-adjust="spacingAndGlyphs"
  text-length="380"
>
  Hello
</text>
```

Could anyone suggest a way to make my text preserve its original aspect ratio if it's not exceeding the width of my container?

Comment: You can use the `textLength` and `lengthAdjust` attributes. If this is not helping you please add an example

Comment: `lengthAdjust` will either stretch the text, or add space around the letters. I just want it not to get altered until it's needed to make it fit its container.

Comment: Javascript & a x axis scale transform is probably your solution